# What is the best way to handle passing different lists to a method?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an issue where I'm having to modify existing code in a java web upload utility (which executes a third party webservice) and having to make all fields in an excel spread sheet "optional" instead of a mix of mandatory and optional fields.  Once the spreadsheet is uploaded, there are checks to validate the data that is uploaded and once validation is complete, there is a class that is used to build a list of elements that are an input into the input xml, and appends the String Array of excel data to those elements.  Once that is built, it is then passed to the webservice to execute.

The constructor method in class HandleUploadUtilVO below assumes a pre-defined list of elements:

```
public HandleUploadUtilVO(String[] row) throws aException {

    clearOldObjects();
    elements = new ArrayList();
    elements.add("order");
    elements.add("order_h");
    elements.add("event");
    elements.add("event_d");
    elements.add("event_d");

    recursiveAttr = populateRecursiveAttribute();

    try {
        mapElementsToAttributes(elements, row);
    } 
    catch (aException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new aException(aException.GENERIC_IO_ERROR, e
                .getMessage());
    }
}
```

As you see in this constructor method, we are pre-populating a list of elements with the given values.  The method mapElementsToAttributes(List elementList, String [] row) requires the input parameters of a List (in the method we iterate through the pre-defined element list and check if it equals one of the values in the list and append attributes and values), and a String [] which represents the excel row data.  This method does checks on the excel data (row) and appends the attributes to the elements (which are already pre-defined in the constructor method and used as input into the mapElementsToAttributes method) and then gets the values of excel data to append to the attributes of the element.

My problem is that there can be a scenario where a field is not populated and an element is not needed (in my case it can be one eventd element or both), therefore the element and attributes need to be removed from the list.  How can I do this when the list is already pre-populated as an input into the mapElementsToAttributes method?  It isn't as simple as just removing from the list before executing the method.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the code of the method mapElementsToAttributes

Comment: It sounds like you may benefit from turning your two data structures into a HashMap.  For example: Map<String,ArrayList<String>> multiMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();